# Footer placed at bottom (img) and content overlay

Tags: css, image, overlay, footer

I'm currently working on a new design for a web site, and I have a little problem with my footer (image) and getting the content to overlay.

For the footer I'm using this at my starting point: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

You can see the new design here: [*edit*]site doesn't exist anymore, sorry about that[/*edit*]
http://nubi.dk/dev/ (content and design is currently evolving thus doesn't fit the question anymore - sorry for that)

What I would like is to have the green part (content) to continue all the way down over the image at the bottom, but for some reason (I cannot see why) it goes behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add "position:relative" in layout.css for #content.

```
#content {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    margin: 0 auto -130px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```